# How to get the config value in Sphinx extension written by me?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have written a Sphinx extension. there is the `setup(app)` function. Inside it I want the config value.

Eg:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('my_key', 'default_value', 'html')
    my_key_value = <something>.conf['my_key']
    print("The value of my_key is: {}".format(my_key_value))
```

In `sphinx-build` command, I was planning to override the value of `my_key` by giving `-D my_key=another_value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app` application object (an instance of `sphinx.application.Application`) provides configuration settings as attributes of `app.config`.

In your case, `my_key_value = app.config.my_key` should work.

Reference: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#the-config-object.

Comment: Hi @mzjn, I was struggling the same issue but couldn't get the instance of sphinx. application.Application? Can you help to get this instance!

Comment: @SushilAdhikari: if you need help, please post a new question.